# How can I disable text highlighting for a JTextPane completely?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, highlight, jtextpane

Please, can someone tell me how to disable text highlighting for a `JTextPane`.
My `JTextPane` is semi-transparent and therefore the highlighting buggy. But no highlighting is good!

I have tried the following:

```
DefaultHighlighter highlighter =  (DefaultHighlighter) chatTextPane.getHighlighter();
highlighter.removeAllHighlights();

chatTextPane.setHighlighter(null);

chatTextPane.setSelectedTextColor(new Color(0,0,0,0));
chatTextPane.setSelectionColor(new Color(0,0,0,0));

chatTextPane.setSelectionStart(0);
chatTextPane.setSelectionEnd(0);

chatTextPane.setCaret(new NoTextSelectionCaret(chatTextPane));
// with:
private class NoTextSelectionCaret extends DefaultCaret
{
    public NoTextSelectionCaret(JTextComponent textComponent)
    {
        setBlinkRate( textComponent.getCaret().getBlinkRate() );
        textComponent.setHighlighter( null );
    }

    @Override
    public int getMark()
    {
        return getDot();
    }
}
```

and something with `highlighter.getDrawsLayeredHighlights();` as well that I don't even remember.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want to allow the user to select text in the `JTextPane` by using the mouse or the keyboard? In other words, if the user drags the mouse across some of the text in the `JTextPane` then that text will not be highlighted?

Comment: Why don't you make the highlight the same color as your jtextpane background that way you won't see it at all?

Comment: *My JTextPane is semi-transparent* - See [Backgrounds With Transparency](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for the probable problem and a couple of solutions.

Comment: @camickr thanks! I could figure it out

Comment: @Abra that's what I meant. My problem was undesirable artifacts that appeared when highlighting text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The highlighting showed some undesirable artifacts because of the way Swing works and I had my JTextPane wrapped in another panel with transparent color.

The eliminate the artifacts, wrap the JTextPane in an [AlphaContainer](http://www.camick.com/java/source/AlphaContainer.java).

```
public class AlphaContainer extends JComponent
{
    private JComponent component;

    public AlphaContainer(JComponent component)
    {
        this.component = component;
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
        setOpaque( false );
        component.setOpaque( false );
        add( component );
    }

    /**
     *  Paint the background using the background Color of the
     *  contained component
     */
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor( component.getBackground() );
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}
```

Then:

```
AlphaContainer ac = new AlphaContainer(chatTextPane);
```

and add the AlphaContainer to your frame. If the AlphaContainer is to be contained in another component, set the other component to `setOpaque(false);`.

Then you can set `chatTextPane.setHighlighter(null);` if needed, to disable highlighting.

For more detailed information see [Backgrounds With Transparency](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) provided by [camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131872/camickr)